# How to do breakpoints in scss file with vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to use media query breakpoints in my vuetify application but in scss file?

For example bootstrap enable me to do that in scss file:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .custom-class {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

what is the equivalent in vuetify? I can't find any [documention in vuetify website](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/breakpoints)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do it in scss:

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables';

@media #{map-get($display-breakpoints, 'sm-and-down')} {
    .custom-class {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

... and you're right there is very little docs regarding breakpoints within vuetify

Comment: Thanks for sharing! With Vuetify 3 this worked with importing `@import '../../node_modules/vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass';`. IDK if this is good practice to import a top-level file or if I should import the specific file that holds the variables. But it works.

Comment: Thanks. In Vuetify 3, I did the same thing but with this import `@import 'vuetify/lib/styles/settings/_variables';`

Answer (score 6):

I achieved this by attaching a class name corresponding to the breakpoint, which is available in the `$vuetify.breakpoint` object. Not a perfect solution, but I only needed to do it for once element in my app. Hope it helps!

Example:

```
<item :class="($vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown) ? 'sm' : ''"></item>
...
<style scoped lang="scss">
#item{
    right: 130px;
    &.sm{
        right: 35px;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I don't like using JS to manipulate style. That could (and should) be done 100% with CSS