# set image height based on breakpoint

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify's image component ( https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/ ) provides a `height` prop. How can I keep that height variable based on the current breakpoint? It would be nice to have something like this

```
<v-img 
  :height="img.height.xs" 
  :sm="img.height.sm"
  :md="img.height.md"
  :lg="img.height.lg"
  :xl="img.height.xl">
</v-img>
```

Do I have to do it with a calulated property or is there a way to solve it with HTML only? By that, I mean I'm looking for a solution like the TailwindCSS approach ( https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height/#responsive )

```
<div class="h-8 sm:h-12 md:h-16 lg:h-20 xl:h-24"></div>
```

I created a code snippet for example purposes

https://codepen.io/dsm98861/pen/qBbXomN?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fcards%2F

Comment: Could you explain what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to change image height depending on user's screen size?

Comment: yes, I want to change the image height depending on the user's screen size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuetify has its own predefined and overridable breakpoints.

I think, the most correct way to solve your problem is to **use computed props**. According to your codepen, it should be something like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      max-width="400"
    >
      <v-img
        class="white--text align-end"
        src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
        :height="imageHeight"
      ></v-img>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  computed: {
      imageHeight () {
        switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
          case 'xs': return '200px'
          case 'sm': return '400px'
          case 'md': return '600px'
          case 'lg': return '800px'
          case 'xl': return '1000px'
        }
      },
    }
})
```

If you are really want to solve it HTML-only, you could set height prop this way:

```
<v-img
    class="white--text align-end"
    src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
    :height="$vuetify.breakpoint.xs 
                ? '200px' 
                : ($vuetify.breakpoint.sm
                    ? '400px' 
                    : ($vuetify.breakpoint.md
                        ? '600px'
                        : ($vuetify.breakpoint.lg
                            ? '800px' 
                            : '1000px'
                        )
                    )
                )"
></v-img>
```

You may be able to come up with a more elegant and suitable solution after reading [the article about breakpoints in Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints/).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use HTML only?

Don't forget that use can change window size and you need to react on it dynamically. Which is not possible with plain HTML. This is possible with script but it's complicated. Using media queries is easy and proper tool.

I don't know what CSS pre-processor you are using. But for SASS you can use conditional styles based on breakpoint (compiled to media queries)

```
@media #{map-get($display-breakpoints, 'md-only')}
  img
    width: 200px

@media #{map-get($display-breakpoints, 'sm-and-down')}
  img
    width: 100px
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry, I don't want to use custom CSS neither. I would like to have something like Tailwind uses `class="sm:1 md:2 ...">`

Comment: Your answer is useful, but you forget to mention that you need to import the breakpoints to be used as "@import '~vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables';" otherwise will give you error. Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/59379289/6531256